$T_0$ spaces and equivalence relation
In a topological space $X$, define $x\equiv x'$  to  mean that  $cl\{x\} = cl\{x'\}$. Let $\ Y $ be the set of all equivalence classes thus defined, let $\tau$ map each point of $\ X $ into its equivalence class, and provide $Y$ with the quotient topology relative to $\tau$. Prove that:

For $\ E $ closed in $\ X $, if $\ x \in E $ and $\ x \equiv x' $, then $\ x' \in E $; hence $ \tau[X - E] = Y - \tau[E] $.

The weak topology induced by $\tau $ agrees with the given topology on $ \ X $.

$\tau $ is both an open mapping and a closed mapping.

$\tau[clx] = cl\tau x $, whence $ \ Y $ is a $\ T_0 $-space.


I am really stressed. It asks to prove the first part of (1), but I don't know how to demonstrate the second part. We always have & $ \tau[X - E]$ $\subset$ $ Y - \tau[E] $.
For the other containment, what I tried to do is:
Let $ y $ be an equivalence class, then there exists $ z \in X $ such that $ y = [z] $, then, since $y \notin \tau[E] $, for all $ x \in E $, $ \tau(x)$ $\neq [z] $ if and only if for all $ x \in E $, $[x] \neq [z] $ if and only if for all $ x \in E $, $ x $ is not related to $ z $.
My claim is that $ x $ cannot be in $ E $, but I don't know how to prove it.
For the second part, we have one containment, the weak topology is a subset of the topology on $ X $. I haven't been able to prove the other containment.
For parts (3) and (4), I have the idea but I don't know how to proceed.

Use MathJax to edit your question.

Yes, of course.

I don't understand how $\tau$ can map “each point of $X$ to its equivalence class”. Did you mean to say “each subset of $X$”?

@MJD Think of it as a natural, canonical projection, like in groups.

Let me just provide a hint for $1$: try thinking in terms of equivalence classes - the first part implies that $E$ is a union of equivalence classes, so the same holds for the complement of $E$.

Does $cl{x}$ mean the closure  of the singleton set ${x}$?

@MJD I don’t see how such a standard notation can mean anything else, honestly.

If it does mean that, then I understand, thanks.

More hints: for $2$, you just need to prove $E = \tau^{-1}(\tau[E])$ for each closed $E \subset X$. This also implies the closed mapping part of $3$. The open mapping part then follows from $2$.

Also, for context, this construction is known as the Kolmogorov quotient.

Let us study these four questions:


For $E$ closed in $X$, if $x\in E$ and $x\equiv x'$, then $x'\in E$; hence, $\tau[X-E]=Y-\tau[E]$.


For the first part: let $x\in E$. Since $E$ is closed, by the definition of the closure of $\{x\}$ (i.e., the smallest closed set containing $\{x\}$), $x\in\operatorname{cl}\{x\}\subset E$. However, since $x\equiv x'$, we have that $x'\in\operatorname{cl}\{x'\}=\operatorname{cl}\{x\}\subset E$.
Now, it is not true that the inclusion you propose is always satisfied. Contrarily, this holds instead: $Y-\tau[E]\subset\tau[X-E]$ (because $\tau$ is surejective). However, here is a quick review of your attempt: actually, what you would like is to prove that $z\notin E$, because since $y=[z]=\tau(z)$ and $z\in X-E$, then $y\in\tau[X-E]$.
Hence, we only need to verify the inclusion $\tau[X-E]\subset Y-\tau[E]$. Let us prove it by contradiction. Suppose that $y\in\tau[X-E]$ and $y\notin Y-\tau[E]$, i.e., $y\in\tau[X-E]\cap\tau[E]$. Hence, there exists some $x\in E$ and some $x'\notin E$ such that $y=\tau(x)=[x]$ and $y=\tau(x')=[x']$. Since $[x]=[x']$, this means that $x\equiv x'$. However, by the fisrst part of the statement, since $x\in E$, we get that $x'\in E$, giving a contradiction.


The weak topology induced by $\tau$ agrees with the given topology on $X$.


Indeed, by the definition of the weak topology, it is a subset of the original topology on $X$. As David Gao mentioned in the comments, it suffices to show that $\tau^{-1}[\tau[E]]=E$. To see this, notice that $E\subset\tau^{-1}[\tau[E]]$ always holds. For this reason, $X-E\subset\tau^{-1}[\tau[X-E]]$ is also satisfied. However, by part 1, $\tau^{-1}[\tau[X-E]]=\tau^{-1}[Y-\tau[E]]=X-\tau^{-1}[\tau[E]]$, proving the other inclusion.
Remark: Notice that we need the assumption of $E$ being closed to prove thath $\tau^{-1}[\tau[E]]=E$. By applying the complementary one could argue that for all open set $A$, this equality holds as well.
Now, let $A$ be an open set of the topology given on $X$. To see that it is also open in the weak topology, it suffices to show that $A=\tau^{-1}\left[\widetilde{A}\right]$ for some $\widetilde{A}\subseteq Y$ open set on $Y$. By the previous paragraph, $A=\tau^{-1}[\tau[A]]$. Thus, we need to show that $\tau[A]$ is open on $Y$. However, by definition of the topology on $Y$: $\tau[A]$ is open on $Y\Leftrightarrow A=\tau^{-1}[\tau[A]]$ is open on $X$.


$\tau$ is both an open mapping and a closed mapping.


By the identity $E=\tau^{-1}[\tau[E]]$ and $A=\tau^{-1}[\tau[A]]$ for any open set $A\subset X$ and closed set $E\subset X$, and by the definition of the topology on $Y$, the openness and closedness of $\tau$ is clear.


$\tau[\operatorname{cl}x]=\operatorname{cl}\tau x$, where $T$ is a $T_0$-space.


It is clear that $\tau x\in\tau[\operatorname{cl}x]$. Since $\tau$ is closed by the previous part, we get that $\tau[\operatorname{cl}x]$ is closed. Finally, suppose that $\widetilde{E}$ is a closed set in $Y$ such that $\tau(x)\subset \widetilde{E}$. As we saw at the end of part 2 (albeit with open sets), $\widetilde{E}=\tau[E]$ for some closed set $E\subset X$. Hence, $\{x\}\subset\tau^{-1}[\tau(x)]\subset\tau^{-1}[\tau[E]]=E$. Thus, $\operatorname{cl}\{x\}\subset E$, so $\tau[\operatorname{cl}x]\subset \tau[E]=\widetilde{E}$. We have just proved that $\tau[\operatorname{cl}x]$ is the smallest closed set containing $\tau(x)$, so $\tau[\operatorname{cl}x]=\operatorname{cl}\tau x$.
Finally, this proves that $Y$ is $T_0$. Suppose that $\operatorname{cl}\{y\}=\operatorname{cl}\{y'\}$, where $y,y'\in Y$. Then, there exists some $x,x'\in X$ such that $y=\tau(x)=[x]$ and $y'=\tau(x`)=[x']$. Hence, $\operatorname{cl}\{y\}=\operatorname{cl}\{\tau x\}=\tau[\operatorname{cl}\{x\}]$ and $\operatorname{cl}\{y'\}=\tau[\operatorname{cl}\{x'\}]$. By part 2, $\operatorname{cl}\{x\}=\tau^{-1}[\tau[\operatorname{cl}\{x\}]]=\tau^{-1}[\tau[\operatorname{cl}\{x'\}]]=\operatorname{cl}\{x\}$, which means that $x\equiv x'$ and $y=[x]=[x']=y'$.

I truly appreciate your help; it has been an easy-to-read proof. However, I still have some doubts, and I hope you can help me. For the part where we demonstrate that for every open set $ A = \tau^{-1}[\tau[A]] $, I proceeded as follows:

Let $ A$ be an open set in $X $ — since our hypotheses are in terms of closed sets, let's move to closed sets — then $X \setminus A$ is closed in $X$, so:
$
A \subseteq \tau^{-1}[\tau[X \setminus (X \setminus A)]] = Y \setminus \tau^{-1}[\tau[X \setminus A]]$ which is not what we want. In fact, we want $ \tau^{-1}[\tau[A]] \subseteq A$, and that will hold if and only if:
$
X \setminus A \subseteq X \setminus \tau^{-1}[\tau[A]] = \tau^{-1}[Y \setminus \tau[A]]
$

Where in the last equality we cannot use the hypothesis of condition 1. Thus, I don't see how to prove the analogous result for open sets.
To prove that $Y$ is $T_0$, you used the fact that $\overline{{y}} = \overline{{y'}}$ implies $y = y'$. Is that a characterization of $T_0$ spaces? My knowledge of $T_0$ spaces is limited to the definition itself.

@C25 For the first question about open sets, it is as follows: Let $A$ be an open set and denote $E=X\setminus A$. Then, by hypothesis, $E=\tau^{-1}[\tau[E]]$. By applying the complementary, we get $A=X\setminus\tau^{-1}[\tau[E]]=\tau^{-1}[Y\setminus\tau[E]]=\tau^{-1}\tau[A]$, where the last part follows by part 1. As how the proof has been developed, it is true that "Following the same reasonings" is misleading. I will change my answer.

@C25 On the other hand, indeed, the property $\overline{{y}}=\overline{{y'}}\Rightarrow y=y'$ is a characterization of $T_0$. I assume the definition you have for $T_0$ is the following: for every pair distinct points $x\neq y$, there exists some neighborhood $U$ of either $x$ or $y$, such that the other point dos not belong to $U$. In this case, checking the characterization is just applying the definition of closure by neighboordoods: $z\in\overline{{y}}\Leftrightarrow\forall U$ neighborhood of $z$, $U\cap{y}\neq\varnothing$, i.e., $y\in U$.
